# How would you usability test wording of an action?

Tags: usability, testing

We're designing a portal where users can create pages with content.  One piece of content is 'embedding' something like a form or document into the page.

The term 'embed' has been confusing in usability tests so far, so I want to create a test specifically around which word would make sense to people.

Has anyone created a test like this? If so, how do you best test for this scenario?

My plan so far is explaining the action then giving users a series of words where they pick the one that makes the most sense to them.

Answer (score 1):

You could do card sorting. Once the user gathered your infos(forms, documents) together, you can ask them / suggest to name the cluster. See if one word specific is chosen by your participants. You'll have your answer

Answer (score 1):

To minimize interaction with your test supervisor, you could provide a search field labeled "enter desired action or keywords" and record what commands or keywords they enter to discover your embedding action.

Answer (score 1):

If you explain it to them using words, they will respond to your question with the same words. 
The best would be to show them a screen recording of the embedding being done and the final result, and ask them to describe it, explain what they saw in their own words. 
This way, you will be able to collect their own vocabulary, without priming them with your own words.